# Robolectric: Typeface objects are all identical when created from assets

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I have custom fonts that I want to test, and I do not want to use Android Tests because they need an emulator/device to get the AssetManager. So I thought to use Robolectric, but I experience this weird issue (illustrated by a unit test):

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 25, shadows = ShadowMultiDex.class)
public class CustomFontUnitTest {

    @Test
    public void typefacesShouldNotBeIdentical() throws Exception {
        AssetManager assets = RuntimeEnvironment.application.getAssets();

        Typeface avenirLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "fonts/avenir_lt_35_light.ttf");
        Typeface avenirLightOblique = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "fonts/avenir_lt_35_light_oblique.ttf");

        assertThat(avenirLight, not(equalTo(avenirLightOblique)));
    }
}
```

I'm using:

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.2.2'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.2.2'
```

But when I run the test, the Typeface objects are the same:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: not <android.graphics.Typeface@3fd1>
     but: was <android.graphics.Typeface@3fd1>
Expected :not <android.graphics.Typeface@3fd1>
```

Does anyone have an idea about what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I would write a bug on Robolectric github project

Comment: I submitted a bug on Robolectric github: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2895

Answer (score 1):

I've refactored my code so that the parameters are the font name (String) instead of the actual Typeface. Now I don't need the context or Typeface anymore, and can write plain jvm unit tests :)